# Function does not work when called as from a mapping

Tags: vimscript, insert-mode, normal-mode, functions

I have a function that depends on the character under the cursor : if it's a `)`, then the function does nothing ; if it's not, the function adds a `)`.

```
function! Ket()
   let char = getline(".")[col('.')-1]
   if char != ')'
      execute "normal! a)\<esc>"
   endif
endfunction
```

If I call it *from normal mode*, using `:call Ket()`, *it works fine*.

But I have it remapped *from insert mode*, as follows :

`inoremap ) <Esc>l:call Ket()<CR>a`. This mapping should (from my understanding) :

- escape insert mode with `<Esc>`,
- go one character to the right with `l` (because escape to normal mode moves the cursor to the left),
- call my `Ket()` function,
- get back to insert mode (`a`)

If I am in insert mode, and my cursor is on a `)` character, then I get what I expect by pressing <kbd>)</kbd> : the cursor moves to the right, and I end up in insert mode.

But if my cursor is on any *other* character, pressing <kbd>)</kbd> only *escapes insert mode*, as if I had pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: See `:h :map-<expr>` for a better approach.  Keep in mind however that insert-mode maps are tricky, and what you're trying to do is a solved problem.  Something like [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) or [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) will do a much better job at handling corner cases than your naive map.

Comment: I checked this help indeed, thanks. As for the plugins, I know the solution exists, but I'm trying to code it myself to improve my Vimery :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of leaving insert mode you could try to do the same without the need for a function (because in this case it's a simple case):

```
inoremap <expr> )  strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
```

Decomposing:

```
inoremap <expr> )
```

will insert the result of the mapping as instead of )

```
strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1)
```

get the current character under cursor

```
== ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
```

if it's a `)` insert the right key, if not, insert a `)`.

---

If you want to keep your function, you can do it as well like this:

```
function! Ket()
  if strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" 
    return "\<Right>" 
  else
    return  ")"
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <expr> ) Ket()
```

Comment: It seems to work perfectly, though I had to take away the "\" in `'\<Right>'`, otherwise a ` \ ` was added each time there was already a `)`. Thank you for the very detailed explanation, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Strange, here it's working as is ...